# Integer division more precise than float division in Python

Tags: python, precision

Minimal Reproducible Example:

```py
int(1414213562*1414213561/2)
Out[6]: 999999998765257088
int(1414213562*1414213561//2)
Out[7]: 999999998765257141
```

The second answer is correct.

Why is it the case that the integer division is more precise than float division. I thought Python would automatically switch from `float` to `double` and even to more precise if need be?

If I know the result is an integer because the numerator is divisible by the denominator, should I systematically use the integer division then for better precision?

Comment: Python integers have unbounded precision. Floating point has 53 bits of precision, which is about 17 decimal digits.

Comment: I understand thank you, I thought Python would up the number of bytes the float takes when needed but it seems I need to use a `Decimal` object rather than the built in Python object.